# Livesearch php and ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, livesearch

I'm having some troubles with my code, I want it to execute the php file whenever I enter something but it isn't working

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStates(value) {
        $.post("search.php", {name:value},function(data)
            $("#results").html(data);
        }); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<input type="text" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)"/>
<br>
<div id="results"></div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "#", "#") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
mysql_select_db("#") or die(mysql_error());
$search = $_POST["name"];

$players = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM players WHERE firstname LIKE '%search%'");
while($player = mysql_fetch_array($players)) {
    echo "<div>" . $players["firstname"] . "</div>";
}
```

?>

Comment: What is not working? Check your browser console to get an idea (Ctrl+Shirt+I in Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Why do you combine `mysqli_connect` and `mysql_select_db`? Do you want to use `mysql` or `mysqli`? (I hope you won't use mysql)

Comment: Line 9 causes a syntax error and I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see,you should change this

```
  '%search%'
```

to

```
  '%{$search}%'
```

in

```
  $players = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM players WHERE firstname LIKE '%search%'");
```

**EDIT**

@user3187651 Assuming you've done everything right on the server side.
Change your javascript to:

```
function getStates(value) {
    $.post("search.php", {name:value},function(data){
        $("#results").html(data);
    }
    ); 
}
```

This should get rid of the error in the client side.

Comment: @Aljie Instead of using the variable $search,he has used the term 'search' and yeah this cannot be the only correct answer as his code has a lot of defects like what Aycan Yaşıt mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `{`. Just do:

```
function xyx(name) {
    $.post("search.php", { name: value }, function(data) {
        $("#results").html(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something that is missing in your code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> //ur getting the jquery via online
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textBoxId").change(function() //triggers when you change the value in your textbox
    {
       var value = $(this).val(); //gets the value of your textbox
       $.post("search.php", {id:value},function(data)
           $("#results").append(data);
        }); 
    }
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="textBoxId"/>
<br>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And in your php:

```
<?php
mysqli_connect("localhost", "#", "#") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());
mysql_select_db("#") or die(mysql_error());
$search = $_POST['id'];
$returnData = ""; 
$players = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM players WHERE firstname LIKE '%search%'");
while($player = mysql_fetch_array($players)) {
    $returnData .= "<div>" . $players["firstname"] . "</div>";
}
echo $returnData;
```

Comment: Gives me a syntax error at line 12 in my notepad and chrome console says the same: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: please try again my updated code. your textbox was not inside your body tag that isn't a correct structure.

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer while looking for something on Google. Just as the OP is in the posted code, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions that do not intermix with each other, and should have been signaled to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For more secure and creative back-end code, you can use this.

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'dev_testing';

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

$username = $_GET['username'];

$username = trim(htmlspecialchars($username));

$like = '%' . strtolower($username) . '%';
$statement = $mysqli -> prepare('
    SELECT name, picture, description 
    FROM users 
    WHERE lower(name) LIKE ?  
    ORDER BY INSTR(title, ?), title
    LIMIT 20'
);

if (
    $statement &&
    $statement -> bind_param('ss', $like, $username) &&
    $statement -> execute() &&
    $statement -> store_result() &&
    $statement -> bind_result($name, $picture, $description)
) {
    $array = [];
    while ($statement -> fetch()) {
        $array[] = [
            'name' => $name,
            'picture' => $picture,
            'description' => $description
        ];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
    exit();
}
```

Advantages of the code

- Prevents SQL Injection
- Orders results from the best match
- Sends a JSON response (JSON is light-weight)

Full Tutorial:
[Live Search with AJAX, PHP, and MYSQL](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/live-search-with-ajax-php-mysql)