# Using AJAX Live Search with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter I have a form for vacation time, and I need to select what user I am assigning the vacation time for. I need help with the following 2 things

1. I need to use AJAX to search for the user and display them under the search bar as you are typing.
2. Once you click on the one you want, add them to a variable and remember just the user_id, so when I submit my form I can send the user_id, To_Date and From_Date.

Below are some pictures to help explain what I need. If someone could point me to a tutorial or some information on using AJAX this way I would appreciate it.

[image: User Form]
<sup>**User form**</sup>

[image: AJAX Search]
<sup>**AJAX search**</sup>

Comment: you can use "live search" from https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144023/6309457

Comment: check here https://www.webslesson.info/2018/03/live-data-search-in-codeigniter-using-ajax-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to achieve this with `<select>` is wrong. Use `<input type="text">` to make ajax call. If still want to make it happen a simple solution with `<select>` will be to load all your employees in `<option>` and use select2 js library.